# Why is my bx-slider not displaying the images in chrome?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, bxslider

The slider works fine in Firefox but not in chrome. The images are loaded but doesn't show up. Even the height changes when clicking on the pager. So what could it be?
Example here: http://flowcenter4.flowworks.de/frontend/screeningroom/yxWJTkdQdFPTAkZJmHcF_layoutcugate2/10/

Code is simply:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
            mode: 'fade',                      
            infiniteLoop: true,            
            adaptiveHeight: true            
        });
        $("#slider").show("fade");
});
```

Like the example on the bx-slider page it should work: http://bxslider.com/examples/slideshow-adaptive-height

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you remove the `float: right;` from `.bxslider` the image(s) show up.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! Didn't even notice that :D